# Import values with certain date into new worksheet tab in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am scraping a Twitter account and listing the results in a Google Sheets table. The publication date of each tweet is added in a separate column in the format YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss.

In a new worksheet, I want to list all of yesterday's tweets. I tried doing so by the following command:

```
=FILTER(Worksheet1!A1:B; Worksheet1!B1:B>TODAY()-1)
```

Unfortunately, the command doesn't work correctly. It copies all the data from Worksheet1 into the new tab. Does anyone have an idea where I made a mistake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To filter yes'day tweet data from the raw data try:

```
=FILTER(Worksheet1!A:B,INT(Worksheet1!B:B)=TODAY()-1)
```

If its still throwing an error I'd double check the date to see if its proper date format compatible for formula based calculations ***OR*** text Date!